# Rails custom model validator fails rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have a custom validator to verify the content of 2 fields in my database.  When I use it through my UI, it works fine, however my rspec tests are failing and I can't understand why.

Here is the rspec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Device, type: :model do
  before(:each) { @user = User.create(email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password') }
  before(:each) { @device = Device.create(user_id: @user.id) }
  subject { @device }
  it { should allow_value('192.168.1.1').for(:ips_scan) }
  it { should allow_value('192.168.1.1').for(:ips_exclude) }

  it { should_not allow_value('192.168.1.1, a.b.c.d').for(:ips_scan) }
  it { should_not allow_value('a.b.c.d').for(:ips_exclude) }
end
```

The Device model is:

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :ips_scan, :ips_exclude, ip: true, on: :update
end
```

And my ip_validator concern is:

```
class IpValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.ips_scan
      ips = record.ips_scan.split(',')
      ips.each do |ip|
        /([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([1-2][0-9]|[0-9]|3[0-2]))?(-([0-9]{1,3}))?/ =~ ip
        record.errors.add(:ips_scan, 'is not valid') unless $LAST_MATCH_INFO
      end
    end

    if record.ips_exclude
      ips = record.ips_exclude.split(',')
      ips.each do |ip|
        /([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([1-2][0-9]|[0-9]|3[0-2]))?(-([0-9]{1,3}))?/ =~ ip
        record.errors.add(:ips_exclude, 'is not valid') unless $LAST_MATCH_INFO
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Ironically, the validator is correctly passing the `should_not allow_value` tests, however the `should allow_value` tests are failing:

```
Failures:

  1) Device should allow :ips_scan to be ‹"192.168.1.1"›
     Failure/Error: it { should allow_value('192.168.1.1').for(:ips_scan) }

       After setting :ips_scan to ‹"192.168.1.1"›, the matcher expected the
       Device to be valid, but it was invalid instead, producing these
       validation errors:

       * ips_scan: ["is not valid"]
     # ./spec/models/device_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Device should allow :ips_exclude to be ‹"192.168.1.1"›
     Failure/Error: it { should allow_value('192.168.1.1').for(:ips_exclude) }

       After setting :ips_exclude to ‹"192.168.1.1"›, the matcher expected the
       Device to be valid, but it was invalid instead, producing these
       validation errors:

       * ips_exclude: ["is not valid"]
     # ./spec/models/device_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

At this point, I'm at a loss as to what is wrong now.  Any help is much appreciated!  Thx!

Comment: Hi, I have also some unexplainable problem, and my method also use $LAST_MATCH_INFO. I think it could be, that Rspec couldn't handle it. I couldn't find any info about rspec and $LAST_MATCH_INFO.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I don't know why, but the RSPEC doesn't know the `$LAST_MATCH_INFO`. If you replace it with `$~`, what it is actually is, it should work. At least, it works for me.

`$LAST_MATCH_INFO` is part of the library `English` which should be enabled in Rspec probably. But for me, the problem is resolved.